Can we make statements about infinity with finite samples in applications of probability?
I was reading about the frequentist interpretation of probability and I am very confused. If the frequentist definition of probability states that probability is the limit as number of trials approaches infinity for the relative frequency, how can this be applied experimentally? Although it may appear that the relative frequency is approaching a certain value, how can we be sure that it truly converges to that value or even around that value?
On a related note, is it possible for a function to seemingly converge at one point, but later switch and truly converge to another? Is there any literature you can recommend me to learn more?

let $N$ be the first integer that does not fit in your computer. Then $f(x)$ that answers if $x<N$ or not will always say no in your experiments but its limit is yes
